# How to find dictionary key with the lowest value where key is in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the key with the lowest value in a dictionary where the key is in a separate list.  I also fear that initializing my variable "key" in the way I am might cause trouble in the future, even though I don't think it will.

```
d = { "a":3, "b":2, "c":7 }
l = ["a","b"]

key = l[0]
for c in l:
    key = c if d[c] < d[key] else key
print key
```

I'm still trying to get a handle on list comprehension.  I have tried something like this to replace the for loop and everything, but it didn't work:

```
key = c if d[c] < d[key] else key for c in l
```

Ended with an invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter to the [`min()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) to pick out a lowest key:

```
min(l, key=d.__getitem__)
```

The `key` parameter must be a callable that maps items in the input list to a value by which you want to pick the minimum item. In your example, `'b'` is the lowest item because `d` maps it to `2`, while `'a'` is mapped to `3`.

Demo:

```
>>> d = { "a":3, "b":2, "c":7 }
>>> l = ["a","b"]
>>> min(l, key=d.__getitem__)
'b'
```

If there is any value in `l` that is **not** listed in `d`, `d.__getitem__` will raise a `KeyError`:

```
>>> min(['a', 'b', 'e'], key=d.__getitem__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'e'
```

You could also use `lambda i: d[i]` to get the same effect without scary direct use of dunder (double-underscore) special methods.

If you want to *ignore* non-existent keys, use:

```
min(['a', 'b', 'e'], key=lambda i: d.get(i, float('inf'))
```

`float('inf')` is guaranteed to always be larger than any other number, so in the above example `'e'` will not be considered a minimum because it doesn't exist in `d`.

Comment: You can use `min(l, key=d.get)` to avoid the lambda.

Comment: @Volatility: or even `d.__getitem__` perhaps to raise `KeyError`s.

Comment: The `min` will raise `TypeError: unorderable types` when `None` is in the list anyway, so it doesn't really matter (it does make it harder to debug though)

Comment: @Volatility: only on Python 3, on Python 2 it'll just return the first item that is not in `d`.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it switched to recommending *\_\_getitem\_\_* over *get*.  The latter is somewhat error-prone because of the possible *None* return value, leading to a misidentification of the lowest key in the dictionary.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: There, adjusted to give a `.get()` as *fallback* option using `float('inf')` instead. That way missing keys are just ignored, not picked over keys that are present.